# How to calculate the rotation and scale from a view's transform property ?

Tags: iphone, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIView which I rotate to certain angle or say scale to a level and then I stretch it from its two ends.
to stretch  I need to change its frame.
Before Changing the frame I need to restore its transform to identity and then only I can change its frame and apply the same rotation and scale again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// save it
CGAffineTransform transform = myView.transform;
// reset it
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
// change the frame
myView.frame = CGRectMake(/*do stuff to the frame*/);
// restore it
myView.transform = transform;
```